# require 'rspec/core/rake_task' どこのファイルを読み込んでいるかわからない

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

rakeに自動でRSpecを実行させるにあたり、表題通り`require 'rspec/core/rake_task'`を読み込ませる必要があるのですが、rspecのgithubを見に行ってもそのようなpathはありませんでした。
モヤモヤして気持ち悪いので解決したいのですが答えに辿りつかずこちらでの質問に至ります。
どなたかご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: [これ](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/main/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb) ではないですかね。

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます。`lib`以下を見るのですね。

Answer (score 0):

`require` した際に読み込まれるパスを得るためのメソッドを利用するとよいと思います。
例えば `require 'rspec/core/rake_task'` した際に読み込まれるパスであれば以下のように得られます。

```ruby
$LOAD_PATH.resolve_feature_path('rspec/core/rake_task')
# => [:rb, "/var/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb"]
```

参考

> $LOAD_PATH
>
> Load path for searching Ruby scripts and extension libraries used by Kernel#load and Kernel#require. Aliased to $: and $-I. Has a singleton method $LOAD_PATH.resolve_feature_path(feature) that returns [:rb or :so, path], which resolves the feature to the path the original Kernel#require method would load.
> https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+global+variables